# Multiple servlets on jersey (no spring nor maven)

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jersey

I have two servlets in my application, i want to show the content of both of them, so i did this:

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>DisciplinaService</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.lab4.club.main.MiApp</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>SocioService</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.lab4.club.main.MiApp</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DisciplinaService</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>      
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SocioService</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When i enter '../disciplinas' or '../socios', i get a 404 error.
However, if i only have one servlet mapped, like this:

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>DisciplinaService</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.lab4.club.main.MiApp</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DisciplinaService</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works with no problem.

Can anyone help me to show both servlets? The problem is in web.xml, i don't know how two show more than one servlet. Notice that i am not using spring or maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `servlet-mapping` shouldn't be the same for both servlet,
Try to map each servlet to different url patterns.

```
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DisciplinaService</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/disciplina/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>      
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SocioService</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/socio/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Indeed, you are correct!
But now i have:
/socios/socios
What if i only want /socios?

Comment: you should change the `@Path` annotation on your `MiApp` class.